# jQuery ajax fails to send one of multiple variables to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax send two variables to php, it sends the 2nd one trough fine but the first variable is always reported by php as NULL, i console log the javascript variable before sendign it and it does return an array of strings so I have no idea what is going on.

```
console.log(givenSpots);
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/map/update.php",
    data: {'spots': givenSpots, 'thisEvent': givenEvent},
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false,
    async: false,

    success: function(result){
        response = result;
    }
});
```

The receiving PHP is:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["adminid"])){
    $currentUser = $_SESSION["adminid"];
} else if(isset($_SESSION["vartotojasid"])){
    $currentUser = $_SESSION["vartotojasid"];
} else $currentUser = false;

if ($currentUser) {
    file_put_contents("update.txt", "0 ");
    include_once "../../../../../../connection.php";
    $event = $_POST["thisEvent"];

    if (isset($_POST["spots"])) {
        $data = $_POST["spots"];...
```

Comment: Please post what `console.log(givenSpots);` shows

Comment: You should check what get send in the post request from the browser, most browser can show you that info from the network tabs

Answer (score -1):

you need to encode your array to json before sending it to php, you can use

```
JSON.stringify(postDataArray)
```

or using jquery $.post :

```
$.post(yourURL, {
    data : $.toJSON(postDataArray)
  }, function(response){
    //do something with your response
  }
);
```

than just decode it with php and use it on your server